# Mysql foreign key by non unique key -- how is that possible?

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys

I was migrating mysql database to postgres and stumbled across the following block in DDL (Note: This is what I got from mysqldump):

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog_property_value` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `property_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sort` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value_number` decimal(15,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value_string` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`sort`),
  KEY `FK_catalog_property_value` (`property_id`),
  KEY `NewIndex1` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_catalog_property_value` FOREIGN KEY (`property_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_property` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;

CREATE TABLE `catalog_realty_property_value_link` (
  `realty_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `property_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dt_is_denormalized` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`realty_id`,`property_id`,`value_id`),
  KEY `FK_catalog_realty_property_value_link_property` (`property_id`),
  KEY `FK_catalog_realty_property_value_link_value` (`value_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_catalog_realty_property_value_link_property` FOREIGN KEY (`property_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_property` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_catalog_realty_property_value_link_realty` FOREIGN KEY (`realty_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_realty` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_catalog_realty_property_value_link_value` FOREIGN KEY (`value_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_property_value` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now, what I see here is that the only unique key in the first table is combination of (id, sort):

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`sort`),
```

however, the second table has a reference to the first on by only id column, which is not unique!

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_catalog_realty_property_value_link_value` FOREIGN KEY (`value_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_property_value` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

So, what did I get wrong here? How is that possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the manual:

> **Deviation from SQL standards**: A
>   FOREIGN KEY constraint that references
>   a non-UNIQUE key is not standard SQL.
>   It is an InnoDB extension to standard
>   SQL.

So it looks like InnoDB allows non-unique indexes as candidates for foreign key references.  Elsewhere the manual states that you can reference a subset of columns in the referenced index as long as the referenced columns are listed first and in the same order as the primary key.

Therefore, this definition is legal in InnoDB, although it's not standard SQL and leaves me, at least, a little confused as to the original designer's intentions.

[Manual page here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Comment: If you see this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html, the first bullet point mentions that foreign keys must reference an index that has the columns use by the index list first and in the same order as the constraint specifies.

Answer (score 2):

This weird behavior of FK's in innoDB is described in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

> The handling of foreign key references to nonunique keys or keys
>   that contain NULL values is not well
>   defined for operations such as UPDATE
>   or DELETE CASCADE. You are advised to
>   use foreign keys that reference only
>   UNIQUE and NOT NULL keys.

PostgreSQL doesn't accept this construction, the foreign key has to point to a unique key.

Answer (score -1):

This is perfectly legal according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key):

> The columns in the referencing table
>   must be the primary key or other
>   candidate key in the referenced table.

Comment: Isn't candidate key is the unique key? Or you are saying that a Many-to-Many relationship can be modeled with a single foreign key? I'm confused :(

Comment: In this case, the columns in the referencing table aren't any key at all (but rather part of a larger key).  In fact, InnoDB seems to allow that to happen.  But it's not standard SQL.

Comment: I don't see how referencing a non-unique key is permissible by wiki's definition of foreign key or candidate key.

Answer (score -1):

The most likely answer is that id really is unique in the catalog_propery_value table, but that the author declared the PK to be the superkey (id, sort) for reasons unknown, possibly having to do with indexing, rather than enforcing uniqueness.

Comment: How could the engine KNOW that id is unique?  It's either declared so, or not, and in this cases it clearly isn't declared unique.